# non-additive noise?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I always hear about noise that is "additive" (as well as being Gaussian),and I guess I'm wondering what the opposite is - what kind of noise is not additive? What does the SDE with non-additive noise look like?

Comment: one could have for example multiplicative noise. But one could imagine infinitely many stochastic models.

Comment: Doesn't it just mean that the noise is independent of the "system", or alternatively that two sources of noise are independent? What is the exact definition of additive noise that you use?